# Scala - Project euler #8

Tags: scala

I'm currently learning Scala and I'm trying to solve some of the Euler Challenges with it.

I have some problems getting the response to the 8th challenge and I really don't know where is my bug.

```
object Product{
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        var s = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
        var len = 13;
        var bestSet = s.substring(0,len);
        var currentSet = "";
        var i = 0;
        var compare = 0;
        for(i <- 1 until s.length - len){
            currentSet = s.substring(i,i+len);
            compare = compareBlocks(bestSet,currentSet);
            if(compare == 1) bestSet = currentSet;
        }
        println(v1);
        var result = 1L;
        var c = ' ';
        for(c <- v1.toCharArray){
            result = result * c.asDigit.toLong;
        }
        println(result);
    }
    def compareBlocks(block1: String, block2: String): Int = {
        var i = 0;
        var v1 = 0;
        var v2 = 0;
        if((block1 contains "0") && !(block2 contains "0")) return 1;
        if(!(block1 contains "0") && (block2 contains "0")) return -1;
        if((block1 contains "0") && (block2 contains "0")) return 0;
        var chars = block1.toCharArray;
        for(i <- 0 until chars.length){
            v1 = v1 + chars(i).asDigit;
        }
        chars = block2.toCharArray;
        for(i <- 0 until chars.length)
        {
            v2 = v2 + chars(i).asDigit;
        }
        if(v1 < v2) return 1;
        if(v2 < v1) return -1;
        return 0;
    }

}
```

My result is:

9753697817977 <- Digit sequence

8821658160 <- Multiplication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [Euler Project](https://projecteuler.net/archives) to challenge yourself and learn a new language is a pretty good idea, but just coming up with the correct answer doesn't mean that you're using the language well.

It's obvious from your code that you have yet to learn idiomatic Scala.  Would it surprise you to learn that the desired product can be calculated from the 100-character input string with just one line of code?  That one line of code will:

1. turn each input character into a digit (`Int`)
2. slide a fixed size (13-digit) window over all the digits
3. multiply all the digits within each window
4. select the maximum from all those products

There's a handy little [web site](https://pavelfatin.com/scala-for-project-euler/) that has solved Euler challenges in Scala.  I recommend that every time you solve an Euler problem, compare your code with what's found on that site. (But be careful.  It's too easy to look ahead at solutions that you haven't tackled yet.)

Comment: Thank you, I saw that in compareBlocks method is not enough to compare the sum of all digits, it must be the multiplication. I changed both for with multiplication. On the other side, thank you for the website, is impresive how short the code in scala can be.